# Can thieves shoot through the hostages?

Tags: die-hard-nakatomi-heist

In Act 3 of the board game Die Hard: The Nakatomi Heist Board Game, there is a hostages tile on the board.  When the Thieves team Shoots, are they able to shoot though the hostages at John? Or do the hostages block the necessary line of sight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostages tile counts as two obstacle spaces for John to shoot through (p.18), so they do not block line of sight.

Given that, I'd say that the Thieves can also shoot through the hostage tile (and it counts as two obstacle spaces when they do) as well.